# Android Studio uso de AsyncTask con mesaje de cargando

Tags: android-studio

Estoy con una app que quiero usar AsyncTask para que cuando hago una tarea que tarda algo de tiempo, le mustro el mensaje de cargando... y una vez que termino esta tarea desaparezca el mensaje y siga correiendo la app normalmente.
Nunca antes use el Asynctask, asi que estuve experimentando pero no he tenido exito. En teoria parecia simple pero es mas compleja de lo que pensaba.
Les dejo el codigo que para que vean la estructura, sepan que soy un novato en esto.

Muchas gracias.

```
public class RegistracionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputFirstName, inputSurname, inputEmail, inputPass, 
inputMobile,
        inputPostCode, inputDateOfBirth;

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        setupProgressDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        registracion();  


        return "Terminado";
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registracion);

   // new MyTask().execute();

    setupActionBar();
    setupProgressDialog();
    setupInputs();


}

private void registracion(){

    UserApp usuario = new UserApp();
    dialog.show();

    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
    usuario.setEmail(email);
    String firstName = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
    usuario.setFirstName(firstName);
    String surName = inputSurname.getText().toString();
    usuario.setSurName(surName);
    String date = inputDateOfBirth.getText().toString();
    usuario.setDateOfBirth(date);
    String prefix = ccp.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus();
    String phone = inputMobile.getText().toString();
    usuario.setMobile(prefix+phone);
    String code = inputPostCode.getText().toString();
    usuario.setPostCode(code);
    usuario.setBalance(0.0);

    if(checkData(usuario)){

        registracionWithFirebase(user);
    }

}
Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            new MyTask().execute();
        }
    });

private void setupProgressDialog() {

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this); // this = YourActivity
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.setMessage("Cargando. porfavor espere...");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas,

Tú código no parece estar mal del todo aunque si algo sucio y te falta algo esencial: Además de crear el diálogo también has de mostrarlo en el momento en el que se empieza a ejecutar la `AsyncTask` y por supuesto, también deberás destruirlo cuando se complete la tarea que quieres ejecutar en otro hilo (`AsyncTask`).

Si no te importa, voy a ordenar un poco tu código simplemente para hacerme mejor una idea del mismo y te añado las partes que te faltan con comentarios para que sepas lo que es.

```
public class RegistracionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputFirstName, inputSurname, inputEmail, inputPass, inputMobile, inputPostCode, inputDateOfBirth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registracion);

        setupActionBar();
        setupInputs();

        Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Iniciamos la AsyncTask
                new MyTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(RegistracionActivity.this);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.setMessage("Cargando. porfavor espere...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.show(); // Mostramos el di'alogo de cargando al crear la AsyncTask
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            registracion();
            return "Terminado";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            dialog.dismiss(); // Cerramos el di'alogo para continuar con la ejecuci'on normal de la app
            Log.d("RegistracionActivity", s); // Mostramos por consola el mensaje de Terminado que nos pasa la AsyncTask al finalizar
        }

        private void registracion(){

            UserApp usuario = new UserApp();
            dialog.show();

            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            usuario.setEmail(email);
            String firstName = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
            usuario.setFirstName(firstName);
            String surName = inputSurname.getText().toString();
            usuario.setSurName(surName);
            String date = inputDateOfBirth.getText().toString();
            usuario.setDateOfBirth(date);
            String prefix = ccp.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus();
            String phone = inputMobile.getText().toString();
            usuario.setMobile(prefix+phone);
            String code = inputPostCode.getText().toString();
            usuario.setPostCode(code);
            usuario.setBalance(0.0);

            if(checkData(usuario)){
                registracionWithFirebase(user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No tengo el código completo por lo que no he podido probarlo aunque he utilizado AsyncTask en numerosas ocasiones y así como te lo he puesto debería funcionar.
Cualquier duda me dices :)

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero esto en realidad no responde a la pregunta solo se re ordeno el código. **Debes asegurar que tu respuesta incluya la solución a la pregunta o incluya una alternativa.** Revisar  [answer], saludos.

Comment: Perdona pero lo he puesto claramente. Mi respuesta incluye la solución al problema junto a comentarios en el código reordenado. La pregunta ha requerido de muy pocos detalles a concretar. Lo he reordenado también porque uno de los principales problemas de esta pregunta era el código mal ubicado.

Comment: @ja2375 hemos avanzado un poco, ahora me aparece el dialogo cargando... pero la app crash despues de eso, creo que hay algo con el metodo de registracion. En el log aparece esto:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3

java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Comment: He solucionado el problema, No me funciona llamar el metodo registracion dentro del doinbackground, pero lo que hice fue colocar el contenido del metodo dentro del doinbackground y despues clean project. Con eso me funciono. Muchas gracias @ja2375